# Converting unicode string to utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Firstly, I am aware that there are tons of questions regarding en/de-coding of strings in Python 2.x, but I can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

I have a unicode string, that contains letter `č` which is represented as `\u00c4\u008d`

If in Python console I write

```
>>> a = u"\u00c4\u008d"
>>> print a
```

I get two strange characters printed out instead of `č`, probably because the actual encoding of that string is supposed to be UTF-8. Therefore I try to use `.decode("utf-8")` but for this I get the standard `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Do you know how I can make Python print that string as `č` in the console?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The proper Unicode representation of "č" is most certainly *not* `\u00c4\u008d`. How did you get to that?

Comment: The unicode of `č` is: `\u010D`, but `0xC4 0x8d` is the binary representation in UTF-8. Wikipedia always helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8C

Comment: @deceze You're right, but that is why I mentioned that it's probably UTF-8 encoded as well. If you do `>>> a = u"\u00c4\u008d"` and then `>>> a`, you will see that it prints `u'\xc4\x8d'` and when you search for that on google, you'll find that the `\xc4\x8d` represents `č` in UTF-8, source: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&names=-&utf8=string-literal

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi You're right. In any case, do you know how I can get from my input string to my desired output?

Comment: This is not an unicode string `u'\xc4\x8d'`. Do no mix things. Forget how things are implemented. Use unicode string or a encoded string (which is a `byte` sequence)

Comment: @leopik:your string is wrong (it uses wrong excape characters). Which python version? Python3 handles natively unicode strings. You may check https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html  (there is one also for python3)

Comment: But this is the string that I have in file and there's much more of them so I have no control over encoding and I have to work with this. @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169684/discussion-between-giacomo-catenazzi-and-leopik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fighting with python for over an hour, I decided to look for a solution in another language. This is how my goal can be achieved in C#:

```
var s = "\u00c4\u008d";
var newS = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s));
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\tmp\test.txt", newS, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Finally! The file now contains `č`.

I therefore got inspired by this approach in C# and managed to come up with the following (seemingly) equivalent solution in Python:

```
>>> s = u"\u00c4\u008d"
>>> arr = bytearray(map(ord, s))
>>> print arr.decode("utf-8")
č
```

I'm not sure how good this solution is but it seems to work in my case.

Answer (score 3):

`č` is not represented by `u'\u00c4\u008d'`.  Those two hex values are the UTF-8-encoded values, so should be written in a byte string as `'\xc4\x8d'`.  Example:

```
>>> s = '\xc4\x8d'
>>> s.decode('utf8')
u'\u010d'
>>> print(s.decode('utf8'))
č
```

Caveat:  Your terminal must be configured with an encoding that supports the character to print correctly, or you will see a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

If for some reason you have a mis-decoded Unicode string, you can take advantage of the fact that the first 256 code points of Unicode correlate to the `latin1` encoding and fix it:

```
>>> s = u'\u00c4\u008d'
>>> s.encode('latin1')
'\xc4\x8d'
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
u'\u010d'
>>> print(s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
č
```

If you have a mis-decoded Unicode string, you should show the file you have or the code that read it and solve that problem.

Comment: @ConstantinHong The OP was Python 2. Byte strings are written `b'\xc4\x8d'` in Python 3 and the real problem was likely the OP read the data from his file using the wrong encoding in the first place